Whenever I have nested layouts the innermost widgets aren't bound by any layout size restrictions in kivy
I am writing an app that on this specific screen needs to have several input boxes within a box layout which represents a flashcard, the number of flashcards is dynamic
# defines default charcatersitics of buttons
<Button>:
    background_normal: ''
    font_size: 32

#defines default characteristics of textInputs
<TextInput>:
    font_size: 32

#Defines the screens within screen Manager
ScreenManager:
    makeFlashcardsScreen:




<makeFlashcardsScreen>: # deifines the contesnts of the screen for making flashcards
    name: "makeFlashcards"# name is used to link it to the build function in the py file
    BoxLayout: # main Layout to hold the Scroll bar feature
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: (root.width, root.height)

        ScrollView: # adds a scrollbar feature along the y axis only
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True

            FloatLayout: # main layout of visible content, easily allows to place the text inputs
                minHeight: self.parent.height*2
                size_hint: (None,None)
                size: (self.parent.width, self.minHeight)
                TextInput:
                    hint_text: "Enter Set Name"
                    size_hint: (.4, None)
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {"x":.05, "top":.99}
                    
                TextInput:
                    hint_text: "Foulder select"
                    size_hint: (.25, None)
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {"x":.5, "top":.99}

                BoxLayout: # a container to hold all flashcards
                    id: container
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    # size: (self.parent.width, self.parent.height)
                    size_hint: (.8,.93)
                    pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}

                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgb: (1,1,1)
                        Line:
                            width: 2
                            rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
                    
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                        size_hint: (self.parent.width, None)
                        height: 80
                        spacing: 20
                        #add image input
                        TextInput:
                            hint_text: "Enter Term"
                            size_hint: (.3, None)# THESE ARE THE PROBLEM
                            height: 30
                            
                        TextInput:
                            hint_text: "Enter a Hint"
                            size_hint: (.3, None)# THESE ARE THE PROBLEM
                            height: 30

                        TextInput:
                            hint_text: "Enter Answer"
                            size_hint: (.3, None)# THESE ARE THE PROBLEM
                            height: 30

                        #add image input

This is the kv file that is being used, the inputs go outside of the grandparent box layout even though size hint should make them a 1/3 of the width of their parent.
The idea is to create something similar to this:enter image description here But a simple version for starters that just has 3 text inputs next to each other and other stuff added around later like a delete button and add image buttons
I previously attempted to change the box layout to a float and relative but those are even more "buggy" or at lest harder to work with and the inputs still placed themselves no where near inside their parent. To clarify I do want dynamic width so that the interface resizes and still looks good etc.

I think your problem is the line:
size_hint: (self.parent.width, None)

in the last BoxLayout. The size_hint values are normally fractions between 0 and 1. Try just removing that line and adding:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height

Also, the height that you assign for the TextInput instances is too small. Try changing the height of every TextInput to:
height: self.minimum_height

